# In Corda, how are attachments hashed and verified?

Tags: corda

I have the following questions about the `SecureHash` generated by Corda when uploading an attachment JAR file to the node:

1. Is the hash always unique based on the content of the file?
2. If the contents of the JAR file change, is the hash guaranteed to change (just like with a normal hash function)?
3. Can the counterparty verify the integrity of the hash (and check the attachment has not been tampered with) at their end?
4. Can the counterparty verify the authenticity of the jar (that it has been signed by the uploader)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In theory, `SecureHash` is a wrapper for hashes generated using various hashing algorithms. However, only `SecureHash.SHA256`, which uses the SHA-2 hash function family, has been implemented as of Corda 3.1. A hash collision with this algorithm is extremely, extremely unlikely.
2. Again, it is extremely, extremely unlikely that if the JAR contents change, the hash will stay the same.
3. Upon receiving an attachment for the first time, the node checks that it is a valid JAR file before importing it into its attachment storage. Instead of being sent the attachment hash by the counterparty, it calculates the attachment's hash itself and uses that hash as the attachment's ID.
4. JAR signing is not implemented as of Corda 3.1. The node simply checks that the JAR file is valid.